# EVariantBadVar: Invalid Variant Type with TBytesField since upgrade to Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-10-seattle

since I upgrade from Delphi XE to Delphi Seattle I got an `EVariantBadVar` when I try to assign a value to a `TBytesField` like

```
procedure Test.SetHash(hash : TByteDynArray);
var
query : TAdoQuery;
a: TArray<byte>;
begin
query := ....
query.Sql.Text := 'SELECT [Key], [Hash] FROM [HashValues]...';
query.Insert();
a := TArray<byte>(hash);
// hash is from a webservice with type TByteDynArray
query.Fields[1].AsBytes := a; // here occurs the exception
query.Post();
...
```

The same code works without problems in Delphi XE.

Comment: Sorry it was Byte not Bytes

Comment: Yes, this smells a little like fake code. Anyway, why are you using `TByteDynArray`? You should use `TBytes`. Replace all use of `TByteDynArray` in your program with `TBytes`. Then you can remove the variable `a` and remove that rather dubious cast.

Comment: TByteDynArray comes from the autogenerated class from a wsdl

Comment: What is the field type of `Hash`?

Comment: `TByteDynArray` and the cast don't feel very good though do they? Are you sure that's the best way to write the code?